# MySQL recursive query that works for one set of data fails for another

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
SELECT @pv:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(idFolder SEPARATOR ',') FROM Folder WHERE idFolderParent IN (@pv)) AS lv FROM Folder
JOIN
(SELECT @pv:=1)tmp
WHERE idFolderParent IN (@pv)) a;
```

The above query works for the following data set:

```
idFolder    FolderName  idFolderParent
   1            adoc        NULL
   2            adoc1        1
   3            adoc2        2
   4            adoc3        3
   5            adoc4        4
   6            adoc5        5
   7            adoc6        4
```

whereas the query fails for the following data set (the only difference is the last column values)

```
idFolder    FolderName  idFolderParent
   1            adoc        NULL
   2            adoc1        1
   3            adoc2        1
   4            adoc3        1
   5            adoc4        3
   6            adoc5        3
   7            adoc6        6
```

spent quite a lot of time but wasn't able to crack. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the post has messed up with the format so i am posting the data sets below for clarity.

Comment: You can always edit your own post. For future reference, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting